# Max heap size is ignored above 12GB

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

Environment:

- AWS R4.XLarge (4vCPU, 30GB RAM)
- Windows 2012R2
- Tomcat 7, jdk-8u102

First, I am not a developer so please be patient. With max heap set to 24GB or 16GB Tomcat only utilizes 4GB and some apps throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. My hunch is GC is "blocking" Java from accessing more memory. The default setting the developers enable for GC is:

```
call :set_XX_java_opts "+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

I've researched a bit and feel adding these parameters may resolve this issue:

```
call :set_XX_java_opts "+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled"

call :set_XX_java_opts "+ScavengeBeforeFullGC"

call :set_XX_java_opts "+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark"
```

Am I on the right track?

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: Can you share all the JVM parameters?

Comment: Install 64 Bit Java instead of 32 Bit.

Comment: If tomcat is utilising only 4 gb why some apps would throw otofmemory ? Get heap dump and analyse what is going on in heap and be sure what is going on there. One nice link you may want to refer https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated earlier, the parallel GC will throw "OutOfMemoryError" , if more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered

Now, we have figured out the problem is with GC running too much. 
This issue could be looked down into multiple buckets :

1. Are you created more objects much quickly than GC can recover ?
2. Are you using the corrct GC algorithm for your use case ?
3. System parameters defined for GC

so, please update your question with parameters for GC.

I would suggest you to first print the GC details using "-XX:-PrintGCDetails" and have a heap dump file using : -XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid.hprof

This would help us in evaluating points 1 and 2 above.
Changing GC Algorithm has a lot of tradeoffs and the correct Algo has to be determined on case to case basis